# Testing Hubot with hubot-test-helper and jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, hubot

I would like to test my hubot scripts, written in JavaScript, with the [hubot-test-helper](https://github.com/mtsmfm/hubot-test-helper) and jest. The lack of documentation makes it really difficult though. I am looking for someone, who is willing to share a working test?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same situation trying to test my bot with hubot-test-helper but with no luck, What I did was try it the same way they are doing in their testings, configuring mocha instead of jest and that works!. so Just review their package.json file and install and configure all as they did, then take the hello_world_test.js example and that should work. make sure you have a test folder at the same level of the package.json file (that's the quick way).